# Do I need both an update & a save method?

Tags: performance, mongodb, rest

Is there any reason I should not use `update` for inserting documents (via `upsert`)?

If not, why is there even a seperate `insert` method?

Edit: I am quite sure that there will be a difference in performance, so I should add the fact that I am working only with small documents, far below 1 mb in size.

Answer (score 2):

Save is meant to insert one document. Update can be used over several documents that match the criteria in the first parameter.

Under certain circumstances (specifying a unique id as the criteria, upsert:true, and not using multi: true) both can serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/), [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) (with upsert option) and [save](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) methods to insert new documents.
However, the insert will be the fastest way to insert a document.

That's because the insert method will just add a document to the end of the collection. The update method first must find the document that's going to be updated and then update it.

Also, if you have an index on the collection, update command will need to remove and re-insert the index entries, which will be slower than inserting new entries in an index with an insert command.

Save method will either use an update or insert command. Save will use the insert command when there is no `_id` field specified in the document and update (with upsert option) when the `_id` field is specified.

The speed difference, however, might be insignificant in some cases. You should probably test it for your intended use case to be sure.